# MySQL master/slave database replication?

Tags: 7, database

Since it's so easy to set up pagodabox with multiple databases (for free), I thought I'd experiment with master/slave database setups.

I have good credentials for both MySQL databases. Everything should be fine and dandy.

The trouble is: At no point does Drupal create tables on the slave DB. I made a module to show me the credentials, and verify the connection, but the DB simply has no tables.

Should it? Is Drupal supposed to do this? Or do I need to do the initial replication myself?

Comment: This is for sure an interesting question. But I think it does not have a lot to do with drupal. Consider moving it to serverfault since it's about database management.

Comment: @BetaRide: The way the question is asked has a lot to do with Drupal, because he assumed that Drupal is responsible for the replication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Drupal doesn't.

Master/Slave replication is the job of the database management system, not Drupal's. All that Drupal does is use it, by using the slave server for specifically marked queries.

To be able to use replication, you either need a pre-configured hosting environment which already provides this or full access to the database server so that you can configure it. Replication happens on a server to server level, not database to database. In short, Pagodabox will most likely not allow you to set up replication.